# In C# winforms using telerik assembly references how to export radGridView to pdf ( Im not using MCV or WPF, implementing in normal winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview, export-to-pdf

```
    using Telerik.WinControls.Data;
    using Telerik.WinControls.UI.Export;

  namespace Directory
  {
  public partial class radForm : Form
  {
    public radForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void radForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
```

// TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'directoryDataSet.DirDetails' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

```
        this.dirDetailsTableAdapter.Fill(this.directoryDataSet.DirDetails);

    }
```

// Button click

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ExportToPDF exporter = new ExportToPDF(this.radGridView1);
```

//The FileExtension property allows you to change the default (*.pdf) file extension of the exported file

```
        exporter.FileExtension = "pdf"; 

        exporter.HiddenColumnOption = Telerik.WinControls.UI.Export.HiddenOption.DoNotExport;
```

// This to make the grid fits to the PDF page width

```
        exporter.FitToPageWidth = true;
```

// Exporting data to PDF is done through the RunExport method of ExportToPDF object

```
        string fileName = "c:\\Directory-information.pdf";
        exporter.RunExport(fileName);


     }


  }
}
```

Some how Im missing something here and my gridview isn't exporting into pdf and no file creation takes place.

Comment: Is the class ExportToPDF from telerik? If not, you may put the implementation on the question.

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders: mate can you have a look now and let me where I went wrong

Comment: What is the telerik version you are using? Have you tried any other format just to check?

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders   I've downloaded the trial and working with it. File version 2012.2.912.20

Comment: Well, i downloaded the trial version and tried here with your code on a radgridview with a simple datatable as datasource. It worked fine, generating a 355k Directory-information.pdf file on C:\\. Don't really know what to try, have you checked windows application logs?

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders : let me check my code once again

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders: rate the question if you like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        ExportToPDF exporter = new ExportToPDF(this.radGridView1);
        exporter.FileExtension = "pdf";
        exporter.HiddenColumnOption = Telerik.WinControls.UI.Export.HiddenOption.DoNotExport;
        exporter.ExportVisualSettings = true;
        exporter.PageTitle = "Directory Details";
        exporter.FitToPageWidth = true;

        string fileName = "c:\\Directory-information.pdf";
        exporter.RunExport(fileName);

        MessageBox.Show("Pdf file created , you can find the file c:\\Directory-informations.pdf");                     
    }
```